# How to add multiple .md files to an Angular library package?

Tags: angular, documentation, angular-library

I created my library well, write README.md, but the documentation is too long to store in one file. So I break it into multiple .md files and now my library structure is like this:

```
/projects/my-lib/src/doc/                 documentation .md files
/projects/my-lib/src/lib/                 project code files
/projects/my-lib/src/public-api.ts
/projects/my-lib/src/test.ts
/projects/my-lib/karma.conf.js
/projects/my-lib/ng-package.json
/projects/my-lib/package.json
/projects/my-lib/README.md                Main page of documentation
/projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json
/projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json
/projects/my-lib/tsconfig.spec.json
/projects/my-lib/tslint.json
```

Now in my README.md I use codes like this:

```
[Read more](src/doc/a-specific-file.md)
```

But if I run `ng build my-lib` the `doc` folder completly missing from `dist/` folder.

How can I say to builder to put my docs into the `dist/` folder?

Comment: Add `src/doc` to the `assets` array in `angular.json`?

Comment: It has been alredy added like this: `"src/doc"`, nothing changed.

Comment: Please give a [mre], it worked fine when I tried it - the files in `src/doc` showed up in `dist/doc`.